# Adding breaker for lighting outlet to CH type box

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have this cutler hammer box mounted in the attic. It currently has a double pole, type ch, 60a breaker for the hvac. It has a couple of extra slots. Is it possible to add a 20a breaker from it to power a light and an outlet? If so, which breaker? [image: Cutler hammer box]

Comment: I don't think so.  Looks like it is used as a disconnect more than a sub panel.  You would need a neutral(white wire not used as second hot) connection not bonded to ground in that box/panel  for any 120 volt circuits(outlets, lights).  You only have hots and ground to that box.

Comment: What year was it installed? Can you tell us any writing on the feeder cable? I'm interested in wire type (fishing for "SE"), size and metal.  It may be aluminum but that's perfectly OK on a large feeder like this.  What does the 60A breaker serve?  Do you have physical access to easily retrofit a #8 ground wire from this panel to the main panel?  Man, I haven't been inside my CH panels for a few years, I forget how nice they are.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica It was installed in 1975. The feeder wire says 4-4-4 AL Type SE. The 60A breaker is for a Lennox air handler. The only access would be the ground wire coming from the feeder wire.

Comment: @Pendley -- I take it re-running the feeder cable is not an option?  Also, how much are you willing to throw at this in terms of money?

Comment: Hmm, the 4-4-4 Al is rated 65A.  The #6Cu NM cable there is rated 55A.  So that's 10A of headroom to play with. That's enough for a light and an outlet.

Comment: That's a /3 cable leaving the box to the load. Why would it have been wired using white as a hot instead of the red that was already in the cable?